# append to div one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am revisiting this code I made a year ago with the help of another person. Unfortunately I don't have contact with them anymore to get more help. Basically It dynamically adds classs to the `tb` and `b` nodes of a document coming from `namesToChange`. Now what I am trying to do is append some text to the `div` with class `dtxt` node but still use this code below. I am using the code `$('td.pn_adm_jeff').children('div.dtxt').append('zzz');` and it works but it constantly appends more than once as seen in the photo below. How do I go about making it add once and stop?

**Photo**
http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/5392/7c23ddb145954aefadb1b9f.png

**Code**

```
   function customizefields(a) {
        $('td b').each(function () {
            name = $(this).text();
            if (name.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
                name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "))
            }
            if (a[name]) {
                this.className = a[name].class;
                this.parentNode.className = a[name].img
            }
        })
        $('td.pn_adm_jeff').children('div.dtxt').append('zzz');
    }

    var namesToChange = {
        'Jeff'    :{'class':'pn_adm','img':'pn_adm_jeff'}
    };

    setInterval(function () {
        customizefields(namesToChange)
    }, 1000);
```

**Update**

```
var needsUpdate = true;

function customizefields(a) {
    $('td b').each(function () {
        name = $(this).text();
        if (name.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
            name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
        }
        if (a[name]) {
            this.className = a[name].class;
            this.parentNode.className = a[name].img;
        }
    });
    if (needsUpdate) {
        $('td.pn_adm_jeff').children('div.dtxt').append('testing');
        needsUpdate = false;
    }
}

var namesToChange = {
    'jeff'    :{'class':'pn_adm','img':'pn_adm_jeff'};
};

setTimeout(function () {
    customizefields(namesToChange);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Where is `$('td.pn_adm_jeff').children('div.dtxt').append('zzz');` in the code???

Comment: why does this deserve a downgrade? such snobs on here :(

Comment: **A.** It's super **localized**, **B.** you didn't show us **where is the most important code being used**, so what's the point?!. **C.** all the answers suggested you to remove the `setInterval` because **you didn't mention you have to use it!** so yes I downvoted this question. Sorry

Comment: @gdoron It's there I pasted the wrong code when I initially submitted my question, but I fixed it. You were just to quick to downgrade my question. The code `$('td.pn_adm_jeff').children('div.dtxt').append('zzz');` I am using is in the `customizefields` function. As for being localized I don't know what you mean by that as I am a beginner at jquery. And changing setInterval was not necessary so again unfair downgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use setTimeout rather than setInterval (interval is for repeating a timer task, timeout is a single timer task)

To prevent a certain task from occuring more than once in a repeated task, there is a simple fix.

```
// global variable
var needsUpdate = true;

// now in the timer task
if (needsUpdate) {
    $('td.pn_adm_jeff').children('div.dtxt').append('zzz');
    needsUpdate = false;
}
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: It's not what he's asking! his comment on the deleted answer:_"the thing i need the setInterval to update the classes"_

Comment: yes gdoron is right i i change that it breaks the code and does not add the classes for the `b` and `tb` nodes

Comment: @Ozzy How would you go about fixing this so that it stays. I noticed after about 5 seconds it removes the zzz

Comment: @Mr.1.0 put any over-writes of the innerHTML under the same type of boolean check. You haven't included the code where its happening.

Comment: @Ozzy I've updated the post...can you explain more on the innerhtml overwrite?

Comment: the `element.append('zzz')` method alters the innerHTML of the `element` by appending 'zzz'. I don't know the jQuery code, but in javascript `element.innerHTML = 'blah'` will overwrite the element with 'blah', and `element.innerHTML += 'zzz'` will append 'zzz'. it seems like you have a method to set the content of the element dynamically, and after appending 'zzz' you are overwriting the element again.

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable to hold the input flag

```
var appended = false;

function appendthestring() {
   if(!appended) $('td.pn_adm_jeff').children('div.dtxt').append('zzz');
   appended = true; 
}
```